# querying results from mysql in the last 3 hours?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

i want to query blog posts from the database created in the last 3 hours,

table

```
blogs{id,blog_text,date}
```

date format: `datetime`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE date > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -3 HOUR)
```

Edit: my bad - replaced `CURDATE()` with `NOW()` as we're dealing with `DateTime`s.

Answer (score 4):

Although @mways's answer is completely correct, it's more readable and less error prone to just use `DATE_SUB` as below:

```
select DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR);
```